Обновление картинки в частичном представлении
При нажатии на кнопку "Load Partial View"- загружается частичное представление. В этом частичном представлении я хочу сделать обновление картинки по запросу пользователя.
Вопрос: как это реализовать?
Пытался через ajax
async function RefreshPartialView() {
    console.log("RefreshPartialView functoin work!!")
    
    $('#searchImgResults').load('/SummaryPlanning/SelectImageAtPartialViewForVarTexProcess');
}

Но ничего не работает... или нужно как то через fetch().. но не представляю как, получается лишь перейти на новое представление, а как обновить именно в частичном представлении, не могу понять, прошу подскажите
Частичное представление:
<div id="searchImgResults">
    @*<form asp-action="SelectImageAtPartialViewForVarTexProcess" method="post">
        
    </form>*@

    <div>
        <img src="@Model.ImageUrl" alt="@Model.ImageName" style="width: 600px" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Input Id Imge:</label><br />
        <input type='number' name='imageId' value="1" /><br />
        <button type="button" id="buttonRefreshPartialView" onclick="RefreshPartialView()">Refresh Partial View</button>
    </div>

</div>

И действие которое возвращает модель:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SelectImageAtPartialViewForVarTexProcess(int imageId)
{
    var images = new List<ImagesCollection>
    {
        new ImagesCollection { Id = 1, Name = "Image1", Url = "/Img/sketches/VarTexProcessImages/Shafts_4/prot_8gr_2ych_glad_2ych/Shafts_4_prot_8gr_2ych_glad_2ych_perehvat_2-02956.png" },
    };

    var image = images.Find(i => i.Id == imageId);

    var viewModel = new ImagesWithAttributes
    {
        ImageName = image.Name,
        ImageUrl = image.Url
    };

    return PartialView(viewModel);

}


Чтобы отправить на сервер инфу, о выбранной картинке, снова поместил код частичного представления в форму: 
Но теперь выходит ошибка: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
